# Bundle Angular Universal app with custom nodejs/express server

Tags: node.js, angular

I just want to know the correct way to serve an angular universal app with an existing nodejs/express server that talks to a Mongodb database and serves data with an "/api/*" route for example.

So is it to have the universal app have its own node/express server as explained here https://angular.io/guide/universal and just merge that with the existing node/express server with route configuration as done here [Serve angular universal app with NodeJS/ExpressJS back-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572030/serve-angular-universal-app-with-nodejs-expressjs-back-end)  and allow both the custom node/express server and the universal apps express server have different ports (because i assume that is how they will be able to co-exist in production)

Or do we use the custom node/express server as the server for the universal app with proper configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To serve angular app with node server first you need to build the app just run the below command

```
ng build
```

And then add two lines of code in your node server file as

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))
app.use(function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
})
```

And after that you can run node server and the default entry index html file will open when you hit the host.

Comment: I knw how to serve an angular app from a node js server.... I need to know if there its the same way with a universal app